# Overriding ToString() and adding to ListBox C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, generics, tostring

Can anyone explain this:

```
public class Test : List<int>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "My ToString";
    }
}
```

If I instantiate this and add it to a `ListBox` control on a Windows `Form`, it displays "Collection" rather than "My ToString".

```
Test test = new Test();
listBox1.Items.Add(test);
```

I thought the add to `Items` would just call my class's `ToString()`. The following works as expected of course

```
MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For that to work you have to disable formatting:

```
listBox1.FormattingEnabled = false;
```

It looks like if formatting is enabled, its doing some magic tricks and the result is not always what it should be...

Comment: I can't believe that listboxes work that way. It took me forever to even figure out the correct combination of words to Google to find this question to solve the problem. Terrible. Good answer though.

Answer (score 5):

Set the DisplayMember on the ListBox to the property of the Test type.

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

To solve your problem, add a Property called "Name" to Type and in the getter call ToString.

```
public class Test : List<Int32>
{
    public String Name { get { return this.ToString(); } }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know that as well...the question is why isn't Listbox.items.add callign my overridden toString()?

Answer (score 0):

Does it not have to be like this:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(test.ToString());
```

I assume you want your listbox to contain a string type?

Not sure if that is correct though, I haven't tested it.

Comment: Of course that works - but Add() receives an object and doesn't it just call Object.ToString() which is virtual? If I change my class to inherit from Object it works...

Answer (score 0):

The items in a ListBox are a collection of objects, not strings.

See [MSDN: ListBox.ObjectCollection.Add Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add.aspx)

Therefore you either have to add the the instance as a string (ex: `listBox1.Items.Add(test.ToString());`) on the front end or on the backend when looking at the listbox you have to call ToString (ex: `listBox1.Items[0].ToString();`).

Comment: No - if you were correct why does adding an int to a listbox work? It calls the virtual ToString() method in Object. If I chanbge my class to inherit from Object it works as well...

Answer (score 0):

I came across this too (and another thanks there Manji!).
I had something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return  MessageText;
    }
```

Where MessageText was a text field amongst several others, and it worked fine. Later I changed it to this

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Concat("[", MessageTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffff"), "] ", MessageText);
    }
```

And it would still return just MessageText field contents (hair pulling time). Interesting thing was that a context menu on the ListBox I had set up to copy selected items to the Clipboard, did use the full ToString override.

Personally I think the FormattingEnabled property should default to false rather than true, I find I often get caught out by the IDE (or control settings) trying to be smart.

///Edit: Typo (must remember not to type with elbows!